# Fragments inside a ViewPager - how to get a list of all child fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, fragmentpageradapter

How can I get a list of all child fragments that I have set up using a v4 viewpager with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`

The viewpager exists on the main activity

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `getCount()` and `getItem(int)` methods to iterate through all the fragments in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`. For example:

```
List<Fragment> allFragments = new LinkedList<Fragment>();
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
     Fragment f = adapter.getItem(i);
     allFragments.add(f);
}
```

See the [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) and [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) classes for an explanation of how these methods work.

Comment: Thansk @Mike. in the getItem(int i) method of the adapter, I am over-riding it to provide a new MyFragment_i(); for different i (to have 3 diff fragment for 3 diff tabs/swipes). So if I call getItem(i) again, won't it create a new fragment and return that instead of the existing fragment?

Comment: That depends on your implementation. If `getItem()` always returns a new item them yes, but if it caches it in some map like a `HashMap` then a single instance is returned for each type of fragment. Also, if you use a collection to keep your fragments then you can just access the collection directly to retrieve the list of all child fragments (which is what you asked originally).

Comment: I think I got it now. So in an implementation like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html , where getItem() returns a newInstance of a Fragment - I would assume that switching tabs after all 3 tabs have been viewed once does not call the getItem() method (if i set setOffscreenPageLimit(2))?

Comment: I would assume that the behavior would be controlled by the consumer of the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Either way, you can force it to always return the same fragment for a given index using the HashMap approach. `if (map.contains(i)) return map.get(i)`, otherwise create the fragment and add it to the map before returning.